# Python+Flask dynamic generated RSS feed is invalid

Tags: python, flask, rss, jinja2

I'm trying to create an RSS feed for my Blog app at patife.com/rss/. The app is built on python with Flask. I tried creating a template that would dynamically generate the RSS with all entries.. but its not valid

- i can't seem to convert date format to RFC-822 using JINJA functions. I was trying the function strfdate.
- the entry actual content which gets inside the description tag isn't taking HTML very nicely.

This is the current code (i removed the link generator bc its working and i can't make posts with too many links)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Patife.com</title>
        <link>http://www.patife.com/</link>
        <description>Startups. I can't help myself.</description>
            {% for entry in entries %}
                <item>
                  <title>{{ entry.title_en }}</title>
                  <link>http://www.patife.com/entries/{{ entry.id }}</link>
                  <guid>http://www.patife.com/entries/{{ entry.id }}</guid>
                  <pubDate>{{ entry.date_created.strftime('') }}</pubDate>
                  <description>{{ entry.text_en|safe }}</description>
                </item>
            {% endfor %}
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: What format strings have you tried with `strftime`? And what does "isn't taking HTML very nicely" mean?

Comment: the string i tried was '%a, %d %b %y %T %z'
the HTML part is that it complains about <p> tags...

you can check on http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpatife.com%2Frss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates are invalid because you are using naive datetimes. They have no timezone information associated with the them. Most databases don't support timezone-aware values, so you'll either need to convert all of your naive datetimes to aware datetimes or just include the timezone in your template.

```
<pubDate>{{ entry.date_created.strftime('%a, %d %b %y %T') }} UTC</pubDate>
```

The reason the HTML isn't validating is that when you embed HTML in XML it gets treated as XML. RSS doesn't support arbitrary tags, so validation fails. XML allows to you embed unescaped values in a node by wrapping it in `CDATA` delimiters.

```
<description><![CDATA[{{ entry.text_en|safe }}]]></description>
```

Comment: this clearly makes the RSS validate. thanks!
however, i still get a few warnings: 1. html content 2. a date problem 3. a misplace item. 2 and 3 are awkward

[link] (http://www.rssboard.org/rss-validator/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpatife.com%2Frss)